# Can´t get typedefs for "classnames"

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, types, npm-install

I want to use the javascript package called "classnames", but no matter what I do, I cant install the typedefs for it.

I already tried "npm i --save-dev @types/classnames", but there is still this error.
Thanks!
[image]

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNEXT",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This library [has its own types](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames/blob/master/index.d.ts) that should work out of the box. Example: https://tsplay.dev/WJ89ZN Maybe post your tsconfig file? What else can you tell us about how your project is setup?